Film set in late 19th or early 20th century Africa, white settlers,attack by lions
I recall a film, but only one scene. In this scene, the white male lead is living in colonial Africa. I think there were attacks by lions. He lived in some sort of plantation house. He is greeting his wife and children at possibly a train station, near the end of the film, and has a vision of the lions sneaking out of long grass and attacking them, but then he comes to and realises they are safe, as he has presumably killed the lions.
I watched this on TV in the mid to late 1990s, in the UK. I can't recall any of the actors but they could have been English or American.

This is the movie The Ghost and The Darkness (1996).  It's based upon an actual pair of African lions who killed multiple people, and the lions are now on display in  Field Museum of Natural History in Chicago, and the movie itself is centered around a railroad project to build a bridge in Kenya.  It starred Michael Douglas and Val Kilmer.
Some more information can be found in the Wiki page, including history on the actual events.
EDIT:
Here's the dream sequence you referenced:



